# What are the edit reject reasons?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt, reject-reasons

Users with a reputation below 2,000 cannot access the review queue to find the official list of edit reject reasons for *questions/answers*.

Likewise, users with a reputation below 5,000 cannot access the review queue to find the official list of edit reject reasons for *tag wikis* (including excerpts).

##### What are the current official reject reasons for edit suggestions?

### References

- [What guidance should be given when edits are rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238333)
- [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538)

Comment: I mean... the focus should be on which edits are useful, not which edits won't be rejected. While there's certainly overlap, we shouldn't be focusing on skirting rules. https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: also related: [How do I make a good edit?](/q/303219)

Answer (score 3):

### Rejection reasons for suggested edits

#### Suggestions to edit questions/answers – reputation limit 2,000

A reviewer who decides to reject an edit suggestion on a question or an answer may choose one of the following reasons.

> - ##### Spam or vandalism
>
>   This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.
> - ##### No improvement
>
>   The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.
> - ##### Irrelevant tags
>
>   This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.
> - ##### Clearly conflicts with author's intent
>
>   This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.
> - ##### Attempt to reply
>
>   This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.
> - ##### This edit causes harm<sup>1</sup>
>
>   Describe how this edit would make the post worse.

#### Suggestions to edit tag wikis – reputation limit 5,000

For edit suggestions on tag wikis, the official reject reasons are as follows.

> - ##### Spam or vandalism
>
>   This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.
> - ##### No improvement
>
>   The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.
> - ##### Copied content
>
>   This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing).
> - ##### This edit causes harm<sup>1</sup>
>
>   Describe how this edit would make the post worse.

#### Suggestions to edit tag wiki excerpts – reputation limit 5,000

> - ##### Spam or vandalism
>
>   This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.
> - ##### No improvement
>
>   The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.
> - ##### Copied content
>
>   This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing).
> - ##### Lacks usage guidance
>
>   Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. See the help center for more guidance.
> - ##### Circular tag definition
>
>   Tag excerpts amounting to, "[tag] is for questions about [tag]" are pointless and usually rejected. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag would be used.
> - ##### This edit causes harm<sup>1</sup>
>
>   Describe how this edit would make the post worse.

---

1. The *causes harm* option is [the only reject reason that doesn't respond with a standard phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits). 
   Instead, the reviewer is asked to use free text to describe why the edit was rejected.

   > This reason can be used in cases where a suggestion should be prevented but none (or several) of the above reasons apply. You should explain why you are rejecting the suggestion so that other reviewers can understand your action.

Comment: This answer would benefit from linking to posts (or containing excerpts thereof) showing how to prevent getting rejected for each reason. I'd edit it, but...

Comment: There's guidance over on Uber Meta that's relevant here: [What are the guidelines for reviewing? | A: Guidelines for reviewing Suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539)

Comment: Your question title implies that your question is about all of the reject reasons. However, this answer currently only covers the reject reasons for suggested edits on questions and answers. There are different sets of reject reasons for each of tag wiki excerpts and tag wikis.It would be good to include those sets too or limit the question to just Q&A. This answer also doesn't explain that the "This edit causes harm" reason allows the user rejecting to enter custom text, nor do you cover the reasons the system uses to reject edits and the conditions under which that can happen.

Comment: All of the listed reasons here are also already listed in the help centre on-boarding for reviewers "[How do I use the Suggested edits queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits)" under "Common reasons to Reject" which is accessible to everyone even those without an account.

Comment: @Henry-Ecker, thanks for the useful link.
It helped me address the issue raised in Makyen's comment (the last sentence).
Another issue is the search engine optimization for the help pages.
As an example, for the search https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Even+edits+that+must+make+drastic+changes+should+strive+to+preserve+the+goals+of+the+post%27s+owner%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com, none of the top ten results points to any Stack Overflow help page.

Comment: @Makyen, *nor do you cover the reasons the system uses to reject edits and the conditions under which that can happen*.
– I don't have that knowledge.
It would be great if someone – having the time and the inclination – would add that information.
I believe a lot of SO users would benefit from it (me included).