# Should reviewers who don’t reject a rude review comment be review suspended?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension, edit-summary

The answer to *Should a reviewer be expected to reject good edits when the language of the summary is rude?* seems to be: yes, you should. And that is based on highly voted answers on [Rude edit summaries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267215) and [Good suggested edit, bad edit summary. Accept or reject?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335458).

So, you are dutifully reviewing an edit, didn't need the edit comment to work out what has been done and you approve the edit. A few hours later you find yourself [review banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424559).

Subsequently in the comments on the answer of that question a moderator states:

> I'd suggest a moderator flag as the ideal approach, as moderators can change the message in the revision history.

and another moderator:

> The edit summary, just like every other input field on the platform, is subject to the CoC.

Now you got me surprised on multiple levels. That doesn't happen often.

I'm surprised that spending time on improving quality on one side but **not** noticing a CoC violation has these severe consequences. I'm not suggesting that edit comments aren't subject to the CoC. They certainly are. The question is if **NOT** handling the edit comment is review suspension worthy (or worse).

First (hypothetical) question: if the reviewer had accepted the suggested edit and consequently flagged the suggested edit for moderator attention, would they have been suspended from review? Or more generally: Am I subject to review suspensions due to not flagging review comments that are not in line with the CoC?

The current reject reasons are listed in [What are the edit reject reasons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424514). If  I reject an edit because the edit comment is a CoC violation which reason do you want me to pick? I assume not the *This edit causes harm* one where I duplicate the offensive wording? Please provide guidance I have to stick to.

If the moderator team confirms that this will be strictly enforced going forward, are you going to retroactively [suspend users from reviewing](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1749071)? Or is cherry picking a more convenient approach?

---

<sub>I can take this further. Suppose you close a question, but you failed to flag a comment under the question that is in violation of the CoC. Do you get suspended?

The point here is: You do a curation task but fail to do another one. Does that have consequences?</sub>

Comment: Can you expand on what about the edit summary being subjected to the CoC is surprising? Or that such incidents should be flagged?

Comment: @Enet4 I tried to clarify that in my recent edit. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Approve the edit on its merits, but report the CoC violation (via the usual channels).

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah, that would be the preferred and level headed out come of this. But I don't have confidence that this is what we will end up with.

Comment: Unfortunately blackgreen appears to [disagree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424559/banned-a-second-time-from-reviewing-for-the-same-reviews-as-3-months-ago/424561?noredirect=1#comment956988_424561) with that solution, @RobertHarvey : *"approving and flagging might be **sort of acceptable**, at the very least it makes moderators aware of something that needs follow up with the user who suggested the edit. However **it’s a worse solution** since a moderator who sees the review task might not see the flag"* emphasis mine.

Comment: @ThomA: Review tasks have permalinks that can be included in a moderator flag, so I don't see the problem here.  The moderator can be directed precisely to where the problem is.  Mods work the moderator queues, so that's where your flag needs to be.

Comment: I don't disagree, @RobertHarvey . Those words aren't mine, as I mentioned.

Comment: "didn't need the edit comment" But you did need it, because "The answer to *Should a reviewer be expected to reject good edits when the language of the summary is rude?* seems to be: yes".

Comment: I'm happy to see that most people agree with this, and that it should not be a suspended reason. But even with this, I'm not un-suspended yet :'( I'll wait until tomorrow

Comment: @Elikill58 yeah, that is not going to happen. I'm pretty sure they are having a mod-fight now and the reviewers will be the casualties. Sorry that you became part of this. Hold strong.

Comment: I certainly would not make it a habit to look at the edit summary. I wonder how many people would. It just wouldn't occur to me to look at more than the title and the body for signs of abuse. My gut is telling me that this is a signal, an awareness campaign is needed and maybe some new entries in FAQs and help centers.

Comment: @rene I'm a bit surprised at your point of view on this. SO has *definitely* had trolls who have *actively used edit summaries* to target very inappropriate comments at users, both on the targeted user's posts and on unrelated posts. I know you've participated in fighting at least one major influx of such inappropriate content in posts, comments, edits, and edit summaries (basically anything with an input box), which happened well before I was a moderator. Edit comments need to be checked and rejected if they violate the CoC. It's part of the reviewer's job to check them and always has been.

Comment: @Makyen we certainly differ then on our view whether edit comments need to be checked and part of the approval call but obviously I'm here on an uphill battle with diamonds. I don't understand why you bring up my involvement in fighting trolls. Some might read your comment as if I'm Ok with users that neglect the CoC. That is a spin I find highly offensive. The discussion should be: How do we educate our reviewers to become better at approving awesome edits and bring CoC violations under the eyes of mods. We obviously differ at which educative tools should be used.

Comment: @rene I'm sorry my comment was taken as offensive. I certainly was *not* attempting to imply that you were OK with CoC violations. I brought up the old fighting trolls issue, because I know from that that you've definitely seen edit summaries weaponized, which, at least for me, was a very clear indication that edit summaries *need* to be checked. But, the impression I've have from what you've written is that you, at least were, OK with the point of view that it's really not part of reviewer's job to look at the edit summary. I was trying to figure out how to reconcile those points of view.

Comment: @rene I realized I didn't say an important part in either of my two comments above. I **know** you're not OK with CoC violations. That knowledge is a fundamental part of my thinking here, so much so that I didn't even state it, twice. That I *know* you aren't OK with CoC violations is a major part of why I've had a hard time reconciling my impression that you, at least in the past, haven't felt that checking the edit summary was part of the suggested edit reviewer's job when I also know that you've seen edit summaries deliberately and intentionally used to violate the CoC.

Comment: @Makyen the only issue is: The edit comment is a minor thing, doesn't stand out and isn't what a reviewer is **primarily** looking at. Of course they reject if both the edit and the comment are crap and in case of  a CoC violation they happily flag the offensive stuff. The point here is that the mod team decided to use the sledge-hammer on those reviewers that approve a perfectly fine edit but overlooked / mis-interpreted a CoC edit comment. The mod team is hampering the trust reviewers have to do the right thing ™. Yes, you need to reach out to us but **not** by your current approach.

Comment: @Makyen Just to answer for your what I asked *Should reviewers who don’t reject a rude review comment be review suspended*: Yes, the mod team agreed that reviewers wil be suspended.

Comment: @rene I'm open to suggestions as to how to communicate with reviewers when they aren't reviewing correctly. A review suspension with a message saying what the user did wrong and how they can improve has, as far as I know, *always* been the method used for that communication. It's what that part of the system is designed for. Fortunately, now, such a review suspension can be very short and still show that message to the user. A mod message is, typically, seen as *substantially* more severe. It's probably not good that just a mod message is seen that way, but they generally are.

Comment: I'll find some more offenders so you can get the communication going. Mouth-to-Mouth advertising it is.

Comment: When I reviewed suggested edits I barely ever read the comment by the editor since it was incorrect or unhelpful more often than not. I just looked at the diff.

Answer (score -16, accepted):

The issue here is *not* failing to act on a CoC violation. Skipping the review would amount to inaction and, needless to say, nobody is *ever* getting sanctioned for skipping reviews.

The issue is **approving** a CoC violation. And giving the editor a +2 reputation bonus for that.

The comparison with closing a question without flagging abusive comments doesn't hold. You aren't organically coming across a possible CoC violation here: *you are actively approving an abusive remark* within a review task. I recommend to read the verb "to approve" not just as the technical meaning it has on this platform, but also in its [plain English meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approve).

> to accept as satisfactory

It is **not** satisfactory to call someone names, even if you do something useful along with it. The edit summary in a suggested edit is part of the edit suggestion. You are supposed to review it. Would you consider warranted a review suspension in case you **approved** an edit that introduces abusive language into the post itself? I hope you would. The edit summary is no different.

Therefore the appropriate actions in this case are::

- Reject and Edit (prefer this if the edit is good except for the edit summary — basically reapply the edit with a different edit summary)
- Reject as "*This edit causes harm*" and explain that the edit summary was inappropriate (prefer this if the edit isn't good or if you are unsure whether it's good or bad)
- Skip

"Improve Edit" keeps the original edit suggestion as a separate post revision, so this doesn't work.

Flagging is left to the reviewer's discretion. Just like when you rollback destructive/abusive edits, it might or might not be necessary to flag for moderator attention *right off the bat*.

> if the reviewer had accepted the suggested edit and consequently flagged the suggested edit for moderator attention, would they have been suspended from review?

Approving the edit *and then flagging*, might be acceptable, to allow for some leeway on corner cases. At least it makes moderators aware that 1) there may be a problem with the edit suggestion; and 2) aware that *you* are aware that there may be a problem with the edit suggestion. I wouldn't have review suspended them, **if** I had seen such a flag, since the main purpose of review suspensions is educational. However the paths we take through the UI are unpredictable. Please don't bank on moderators being able to see these things in any particular order.

Comment: I'm not *approving a CoC violation* because that is not what I'm reviewing. I'm reviewing an edit that *also* happens to have a comment that I don't need to read or even see to approve an edit. Getting suspended over this is nonsense.

Comment: @rene the edit message is part of the edit suggestion. I'm not sure why you refuse to accept this fact. If it weren't, it would be a non-editable auto-generated summary, instead of an input field, and moderators wouldn't have a tool to redact it as needed.

Comment: I somewhat agree with rene here, the edit summary can easily be missed compared to the post body, you can say it is like reading the fine print.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You can say the the suspension is teaching you a lesson in review that you will never forget & forever follow.

Comment: "Approving the edit and then flagging, might be acceptable." How? It is approving the violating summary.

Comment: @philipxy not particularly, I probably wouldn't have missed that edit summary (It is the easiest thing to look at in side by side markdown mode, the rest of the colors aren't that easy on the eye) but I can see how it is possible to miss it.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I don't understand what that has to do with my point, which includes that whether one can be expected to know what to do before the suspension could be considered irrelevant. Because, speaking of things "possible to miss", the suspension is not possible to miss.

Comment: @philipxy I am basically saying that this particular suspension isn't teaching me any lesson since 1. It is not me who is suspended 2. I probably won't have ignored the summary 3. I am particularly not interested in visiting the review queues and rather prefer to curate posts during my normal usage of the site.

Comment: This is a pretty slippery slope. I don't even look at the summary when reviewing an edit unless it's unclear to me why the change was made, they're supposed to be nothing more than clarifying; if an edit was clear then the default summary is fine, in which case, why would you look at it? Calling it "approving" the edit summary and indeed suspending for it is utterly moronic.

Comment: Frame challenge: do people who put rude comments on their edit suggestions actually expect that comment to be read by any specific individual?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no, but from now on everyone that approves a suggestion has to, so you have an audience among reviewers.

Comment: @rene indeed, that sounds like it created a problem where there was none.

Comment: I totally agree with Nick. I have ~4k edit reviews, and I barely ever read the message when the edit is good. I usually only check them if it's unclear why the edit was made. The edit queue already has way too many reviews and too few reviewers. Don't make it even less attractive to review.

Comment: Folks, frankly, it is quite disappointing to see the "I am not supposed to check the edit summary" reaction. As an active reviewer too (2.2K+ under the belt), I do not understand how can we say it's not our job to read the edit summary. Were it a case of a nonsensical summary or a badly written one, I'd understand, but approving something that contains a direct offence? Come on. Also note that moderators do not have fine-grained tools to address that (warn the reviewer, for example). The only way to bring an incorrect vote to a user's attention is to issue a review suspension.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine **the only slippery slope is letting abuse through**. I honestly don't understand on what basis you would think that reviewers should get a free pass here. You are right that edit summaries are "supposed to be nothing more than clarifying". Just like comments! And look, people insult each other in comments all the time. If the concern is that the edit summary isn't prominent enough on the review UI, then that's a feature request for the company; it is **not** a reason to exempt reviewers from paying attention.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine "_Also note that moderators do not have fine-grained tools to address that_" then I believe it is time they got them. The community keeps having the discussion that it lacks users for the review queues yet we keep pushing away the reviewers (volunteers) for minor oversights.

Comment: "have you tried not being poor?". It's not as simple as "it is time they got them". The tooling's been requested, more than once. The rest hinges on SE doing anything about it (and good luck with that). I am also unsure whether approving an edit replacing a slightly condescending sentence with a revision with a summary that's actually offensive is a "minor oversight", but, I guess, to each their own.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine mods do have tools. Mod messages still work last time I checked. And while I wasn't planning on finding all prior art in SEDE, I don't expect many cases. And if this remains review suspension worthy (and it looks like that will be the case) then the existent guidance needs updates to make that utterly clear. No-one likes surprises.

Comment: @rene IMO it'd be a more serious measure to make this into a profile-level warning instead of keeping it within the scope of reviews *and* it disperses information. If a moderator were to come across a repeated instance of poor or incorrect reviews, it's not guaranteed that they'd look at the history of profile-level warnings to see if there was any prior issue. I wouldn't necessarily look there. Reviews are reviews, and shouldn't be conflated with site-wide misbehavior

Comment: "I honestly don't understand on what basis you would think that reviewers should get a free pass here." On the basis that, *in the object example under discussion, the proposed edit was clearly a net positive to the site*.

Comment: You talked about a CoC violation, those don't come in 50-shades of grey (nor Cody Gray), right? Specially not with the new shenanigan's on the doorstep.

Comment: @rene I'm not talking about disciplinary action towards the editor. I'm talking about reviewers. It's not the reviewer who committed a CoC violation, which would warrant  profile-level discipline. The reviewer failed to stop the abuse from harming the victim due to overlooking part of the edit suggestion. That is a review failure which has to be addressed in the review system.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel and it was a net negative to the victim of the abuse. I'm baffled that you folks seem to not find this a definite "no go".

Comment: "and it was a net negative to the victim of the abuse" - That's just it. Per my first comment, I do not believe you can identify any actual such person.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it was obviously the person who authored the post on which the edit was suggested, and you should also consider that we moderators became aware of the issue somehow. Actually, it was even [publicly discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424548/how-can-report-an-offensive-edit-summary). We don't just mysteriously find people to review-ban.

Comment: I don't think that person was a victim of abuse, because I don't see any reason to suppose that said person was intended to read the message, nor that said person actually did so.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel they literally asked a Meta question about it, which I just linked.

Comment: I am going to go on the disagreement bandwagon here. This is an example of treating people like robots. Stop. They're human beings. The summary is going to be systematically overlooked during review. Period. Deal with it in another way than punishment. Fix the review design so it is harder to overlook it. Run an awareness campaign. Do something constructive with it, please.

Comment: To be honest, what I *also* don't get is the outcry about reviewer feelings over a 2-day timeout. We keep telling users they are silly if they say that hurts their feelings. Yet as soon as one of us is put on a timeout (which is not a punishment last time I checked - it's not on the permanent record, it doesn't count against being elected as a moderator, it just temporarily disables reviewer privileges), there is talk about hurting the feelings of reviewers. What's more, I don't get how a red line in the middle of the screen is easy to overlook. I also have to restate that doing [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] something about the queues is outside our control. We tried time and time again, but that all depends on SE doing anything about it. Should we dance around every reviewer until that happens out of the fear they stop? No, I don't think so. @rene, re: warning - I am sure you know that sending a warning message puts the "offense" on the user's permanent record - is it really better than a small timeout?

Comment: P.S. I do agree, though, with that this likely needs to be spelled out loud and clear in the guidelines so as to avoid surprise suspensions from reviewing.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine we don't hold grudges to users. Mods who do should reconsider their diamond.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine The guidelines for reviews are the collective contents of MSO and MSE. That's been the case basically forever. I can remember when I was just starting reviewing and needed to read a boatload of MSO posts to understand the nuances of what's required. Should such instructions be consolidated into one place: yeah, that would be great. As for the issue of how reviewers are to to handle R/A content in edit summaries, that's been [clear since at least 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267234/3773011), which is that the edit should be rejected and flagged if a pattern.

Comment: The moderator action when someone isn't following the guidelines for reviewing has been, for a very long time, that a review suspension is issued with an explanation which helps the user learn what they are doing wrong. It used to be that review suspensions needed to be long to be sure it was shown to the user. Fortunately, the system has been changed such that even short review suspensions result in the review suspension message being shown, so such review suspensions can be quite short. It would be nice if the system had a review message without suspension option for mods, but it doesn't.

Comment: thanks for the link, @Makyen, despite me having a full bookmarks folder on the rules of reviews, that one wasn't there! I can attest that the guidance is a bit... scattered all over the place and would likely benefit from consolidation effort. If I have time in the near future, I'll try to spearhead such a project given my interest in the review queue system.

Comment: @rene of course, I know we don't (at least I sincerely hope we don't). My point was that I am unsure that sending a warning message to the user's email while also putting that warning on their permanent record (there is a difference between verbal and written reprimands for a reason) is of greater benefit than just timing them out for a little while  + providing them with the link to the review that lead to said timeout. I'd prefer there to be transient review queue warnings instead, but we both know it will be probably take SE another 6-8 to get to that.

Comment: Just some clarification on *you are actively approving an abusive remark within a review task.*. This only goes for text entered as part of the review task, right? Already present comments that are a CoC violation can be left untouched without consequences? That counts as an inaction, right?

Comment: @rene comments under the post aren't affected by the outcome of the review task, and interaction in comments isn't what generates a new review task in the system, therefore comments are outside its scope. Of course flagging CoC violations in those comments as you spot them is a useful thing to do, but I don't think it should be conflated with the review task itself, nor that moderators should take this into account when determining the correctness of the review.

Comment: If reviewers are supposed to flag rude edit comments, then why is there no flag option in the suggested edit review queue? And why isn't it mentioned anywhere in the review guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits)? I think you are confusing two different things: 1) reviewing the edit itself in its own merit, and 2) reporting someone for CoC violations. Notably the average user has no _responsibility_ to act as CoC police, that's a diamond moderator duty.

Comment: @Lundin you aren’t required to *flag* rude edit comments (also called edit summaries). You are required to *reject* them, as they are part of the edit suggestion. And “reject” obviously is a review option in the suggested edits queue. Flagging any possible abuse for further moderator follow up is up to the reviewer.

Comment: +1, I agree wholeheartedly with this answer. An edit reason/comment is part of the revision and displayed prominently/permanently against that revision. To approve (physically push the button), is to approve (allow) that content on the site. I don't get why this is controversial. Review bans exist so you learn something: If you're getting review banned for approving harmful revision comments, the learning here is to pay more attention to the review comment.

Answer (score 13):

It's a shame that this particular situation was conflated with a reviewer ending up suspended from the review queues. This had not even been the reviewer's first mistake, plus the suspension was not that long, yet people felt too strongly about the fact that overlooking a code of conduct violation during reviews is a serious issue and had its consequences.

All curation on this platform must have some form of code of conduct enforcement alongside it. In other words, if you find something which amounts to a CoC violation during any of the site's curation activities, ignoring it amounts to doing half the task at best, and contributing to the problem at worst. Do not underestimate it. This part in particular is nothing new in the world of finding self-vandalisms or self-additions of meta-commentary with rude content.

Curation is, and will continue to be, thankless work that needs to be done carefully, and for which curators will continue to be held accountable. The tools in place are not perfect and have tripped reviewers at times. But when they do trip and cause someone to temporarily lose the privilege to enter the queues, *the solution never was to relax the curation criteria*. If anything, the UI was adjusted so that we had a clearer idea of what to choose. And if not, we *educated the reviewers* so that the mistake isn't made again.

With that said, given that so many people have very clearly announced that they are very unlikely to see the edit message during the review of edit suggestions... now this is something that may have to be looked into. My suggestions would be:

- Change the font size of the edit message to match the post body's, which would make it harder to skip with your eyes.
- Add a **flag** button directly in the Suggested edits review queue, so that it is easier to report rude edits. When attempting to modflag, it could include a starter text such as "reported through suggested edit 1234567")
- If it were possible to change the edit message entirely so that it does not appear in the review history, we could make it clear in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits) and in the review page itself about this. Best done alongside the flag capability above, so that the incident would be followed if necessary. But no, currently reviewers cannot redact edit messages.

But I would rather not see these changes as something that we absolutely needed to get things right. We really should not let these cases slip. The feelings of reviewers who made a mistake are not more important than the feelings of victims subjected to abuse.

Comment: This *precisely* describes the issue I take with the whole situation. A mistake is still a mistake no matter who made it. Not looking at edit summaries is an active choice (the summary *is* presented during review, after all), but it's not different from choosing to overlook the title or tags - it's fine as long as nothing happens, it's a mistake if something does. Which did happen in the case at hand. And yes, if so many peers indicated that the summary is easy to overlook (which I still have trouble understanding as of how), then we may have identified another problem with the queues [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] that needs fixing. But that fact doesn't absolve the reviewer from the responsibility of treating a review item as a holistic entity that includes several parts: the edit summary, the body, and the tags.

Comment: It is only possible for mods to edit the comment in the revision history and that doesn't retroactively redact the comment as shown on the review. I've verified that elsewhere.

Comment: Your answer is a breath of fresh air. It's refreshing to read some constructive suggestions for potentially improving the situation, rather than just focusing on the rights and wrongs of what has already happened.

Comment: Hm can we consistently name it "temporarily suspended" instead of "banned" ? IMO the use of the word banned as a catch all for "can't do it anymore" is kind of adding fuel to the fire by making it appear worse than it is. "Banned" implies you can't do it anymore for a long time, not true in this case.

Comment: Sure, @Gimby. My intent was to use the [right nomenclature](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions), which turns out is the one that you edited in. 

Comment: A good solution would actually be to add a new approval reason; "approve and edit summary (summary did not meet our standards)", and provide only +1 reputation for the edit.